# Batch file: Concatenating list of files from array

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of files, say `a`, `b` and `c`. If I need to concatenate them in that order into a single file, I'd use:

```
copy /B a+b+c outputfile
```

How do I do the same if the filenames are in an array? Eg:

```
set FILE_LIST=(a b c)
```

I don't want to specify each file name when copying, and wondering if I could just iterate the array and concatenate.

Comment: Here's the simple answer
http://superuser.com/questions/191224/populating-array-in-dos-batch-script

Regards,
VIshnu

Comment: @VishnuPrasadKallummel: That seems to answer how to copy files one by one. How do I concatenate them like above? Not sure if it can be done individually.

Comment: Concatenat means appending right? So you can append the files one after the other?
Would this work for you? http://superuser.com/a/752473/235648

Comment: @VishnuPrasadKallummel Thanks! It did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by going through a for loop for the file and concatenating/append the files one by one again in another for loop.

List of files in an array:
[Populating Array in DOS Batch Script](https://superuser.com/questions/191224/populating-array-in-dos-batch-script)

The appending the list of files with a for loop:
[A command-line or batch cmd to concatenate multiple files](https://superuser.com/questions/111825/any-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files/752473#752473)

Regards,
Vishnu